# keycloak email template use client base url

Tags: email, keycloak, freemarker

I am trying to use client base url or realm frontend url in requiredActions.ftl and password-reset.ftl. How can I do that? I cant use theme properties as we only have one keycloak instance with different realms as environments and I will use same email theme for these environments but base urls will change across these realms/clients.

My tried ideas:

client.getBaseUrl

session.getContext.getClient.getBaseUrl

these didnt work out. I only want to use this realm/client base url to generate my new password reset link which will use base url and user id.

Comment: The client base url is different per client while the realm frontend url is the same for all clients in the realm. Can you please explain what you are trying to achive?

The corresponding Keycloak link to reset the password is available via the `link` attribute.